# What does 'flip' mean?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election

At this moment, the [NYT results](http://www.nytimes.com/elections/results/president) shows Ohio as "Flip" for Trump. What does that mean?

[image]

Comment: I believe it is 'flipped' from the previous presidential election.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It simply means that the state voted for a different party from 2012.

So, if the state was won by Democrats in 2012, and it's won by Republicans this year, the state flipped, vice versa.